# Change paths from slash to backslash in a file with powershell

Tags: regex, bash, powershell

I have a config file originating from a unix environment, where the basepath is replaced with the basepath in windows:

```
inputdir = D:\etl-i_win_4/input/000/
inputdir = D:\etl-i_win_4/input/001/
inputdir = D:\etl-i_win_4/input/002/
inputdir = D:\etl-i_win_4/input/003/
inputdir = D:\etl-i_win_4/input/004/
inputdir = D:\etl-i_win_4/input/005/
inputdir = D:\etl-i_win_4/input/006/
inputdir = D:\etl-i_win_4/input/007/
inputdir = D:\etl-i_win_4/input/008/
inputdir = D:\etl-i_win_4/input/009/

movepostcmd = D:\etl-i_win_4/divider/bin/os-independant/divider.postprocessing

ctrldir = D:\etl-i_win_4/divider/applogs/

lockglob = /opt/netmind/test/etl-festo/kette/divider/applogs/dividerglob.lock
```

I need proper windows paths with backslashes. How would a function look like, that reads the config file, identifies the lines with windows paths, and replaces all `/` with `\`? Note that the last line with a unix path should be ignored.

Comment: In PowerShell, generally, backslash and forward slash in paths are interchangeable. So, are you really sure that you *do* need to replace the forward slashes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir

Comment: @Klas: That's a config file for a c++ programm. It doesn't like windows paths with slashes in it. So yes I need to replace them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try thid to replace all path:

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\config.txt" | % {$_ -replace '/','\'} | set-content "C:\temp\config Bis.txt"
```

Just for Windows path accordind to the fact each line containing a Windows path match "A_LETTER:\" patern ... not so good, but it can do the job :

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\path.txt" | % {if ($_ -match "[A-Z]:\\"){$_ -replace '/','\'}else {$_}} | set-content "C:\temp\path Bis.txt"
```

Comment: I'd make the pattern either just `[A-Z]:` or `[A-Z]:[\\/]`, in case the first path separator is a `/` too.

Answer (score -1):

You could also try using .Net Path class:

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\config.txt" | % { [System.Io.Path]::GetFullPath($_) }
```

Comment: That would also transform Unix paths into Windows paths.